# swift3 iOS how to handle possible nil view in closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures

i have a view controller that allows ne to create messages. While posting it to the server, the user might close the view down. Now inside the alamo fire closure i have functions changing the UI depending on the state. If the user has closed the view already, it creates a crash. How can i handle this?

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the view as a weak parameter, and then do UI changes only if it's still relevant.
Simple example:

```
doSomething() { [weak self]  in
            self?.updateText()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From Apple Developer website. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

```
Conversely, define a capture as a weak reference when the captured reference may become nil at some point in the future.
```

Example :

```
func updateMyView(){ [weak self] in 
      self?.updateView()
    }
```